# How can I call eglSwaptInterval using AndroidNDK?

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, swap

I need to set the interval in eglSwapInterval to 0 for my application, however I need to know the EGLDisplay for this. Is this call supported in Android, and if so how can I call this using GLSurfaceView (or do I need to call this from the native code?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have managed to call it from the native side, (I cannot find a way to call it from Java):

```
 eglSwapInterval(eglGetCurrentDisplay(), 0);
```

I am assuming that I don't need to call eglSwapBuffers myself, as this seems to be happening already somewhere by the Android system.